# send request, Accept/decline operation from an user to another user in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, authentication

iam developing an website in which the user1 create an account and send request to user2. if user2 accepts then the user1 will be able to see the profile pic else user1 cannot.

i dont know how to search for this specific controls to the user?
 i tried some logic 
 in my frontend i have created two buttons

```
<button type="button">SEND REQUEST</button>
<button type="button">CANCEL</button>
```

and the above buttons should not work in their own profiles,

if user1 clicks on send request button it needs to send notification to the user2 in popupbox whether to accept or decline like below

```
<button type="button">ACCEPT</button>
<button type="button">DECLINE</button>
```

if user2 accepts, info of user2 should be visible only to the user1.
 how can i achieve it ?
 i just need a link to refer this kind of issue or logic to be done,
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need something to connect these 2 clients. It may be done via sockets on both client sides or by polling the server side which in turn should save that info in some data structure.